# UITableView RowActions : Do not dismiss row actions?

Tags: ios, swift3, uikit, tableview

I have a tableview which uses two tableview row Actions one is delete and other is more.

When I tap on more button an alertcontroller is presented which has some actions.
I want that when morebutton is tapped the alertcontroller is presented but the rowActions remain there itself showing on which row the more button was pressed however it fades away as soon as I tap the more button.

Apple mail app and whatsapp do this successfully.

I am using xcode 9 and ios 11.1 in simulator.

I have used below code for implementing swipe to action functionality:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let conversation = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    let conversationId = Int(conversation.id)
    let conversationType = Int(conversation.conversation_type_id)
    let deleteTitle = getDeleteRowActionTitle(conversationId: conversationId, conversationType: conversationType)
    let moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "More", handler:{action, indexpath in
        self.moreAction(conversation: conversation, conversationId:conversationId,conversationType:conversationType,indexPath:indexpath)
    })
    moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.destructive, title: deleteTitle, handler:{action, indexPath  in

    })
    return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction]
}
 func moreAction(conversation:Nd_conversation,conversationId: Int,conversationType:Int,indexPath:IndexPath){

    let muteTitle = notify ? "Mute" : "Unmute"
    let moreActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: muteTitle, style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

    })
    moreActionSheet.addAction(action1)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(action) -> Void in })
    moreActionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(moreActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is working in ios 10.3 but not in ios 11.

Comment: I have an answer for this question.If anyone is stuck in this problem please upvote the question and I will answer this.